# What is this instrument?

Tags: avionics, flight-instruments

I am looking to sell this instrument, but it has no part numbers or any other identifying marks other than it says "Kollsman" on the back.  Anyone know what it is and what it might be worth?
[image]

Comment: "Anyone know what it is and what it might be worth?"  -yes.

Comment: $175 https://aeroantique.com/collections/artifacts-that-have-moved-on/products/accelerometer-g-meter-an-5745?variant=38275923402

Comment: I will give you $50 for it.

Comment: Both needles are pointing to -5 in a 1G environment, which suggests to me that perhaps the instrument may be broken.  One of those needles should be pointing to "1".

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5):

As the face says, it's a "G meter", aka "accelerometer". It measures vertical acceleration in units of "G" (i.e. acceleration due to gravity, 9.8 m/s^2 or 32 f/s^2).

Price would vary, but here's a site with a similar instrument which sold for $75 when it was in stock: https://aeroantique.com/products/accelerometer-g-meter-1?variant=39681371274